# How to get depth and IR data from realsense R200

Tags: ros, rviz, realsense, realsense-camera, rqt-image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I've compiled with catkin_make the Intel Real Sense package: https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense with no errors and I'm able to display colored images by using:

```
rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view
```

and selecting the topic:

```
/camera/color/image_raw
```

If I select other topics like

```
/camera/infrared1/image_raw
/camera/depth/image_raw
```

I only get a black screen.

If I try to follow this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/RealSense_R200 and I load the file realsenseRvizConfiguration1.rviz I get only the colored image and the other windows related to depth and infrared options are black.

Can you help me please?
I would like to capture both infrared and depth data coming from the R200 sensor.

I would like to show the same data as showed in this screenshot: http://wiki.ros.org/RealSense_R200?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=snapshot.png in order to get an environment map.

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233820/how-to-get-depth-and-ir-data-from-realsense-r200/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-05-11**:
no tips? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, try running the librealsense binaries first. If it's still black for IR views, make sure you run the patch for uvcvideo. Check out https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense/issues/12

---

Originally posted by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) with karma: 194 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-05-19**:
The IR view works well if I run the librealsense binaries but only get a black screen under ROS. :(

**Comment by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) on 2016-05-19**:
Try using the instructions on the Github readme for the ROS driver

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-05-19**:
Yes, I solved it by installing the ROS driver! Now, it seems to work well!! thank you!

**Comment by [Ark](https://answers.ros.org/users/29693/ark/) on 2017-03-14**:
Hi Marcus, could you please give any details on how to install the ROS driver to fix this problem?  Many thanks!

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2017-03-14**:
I followed the instructions on this page: http://wiki.ros.org/RealSense